# Django: Settings in database

Tags: django

How do you store and use database-backed settings for your Django project? How do you cache them?

What problems do you encounter?

Comment: This is a pretty vague question - can you elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish? For instance, are you wanting to store per-user settings (if so use the profile module), or specific application settings (if so use some sort of middleware).

Comment: I'm asking for people experience in storing Django's settings plus modules settings plus per-user settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[django-livesettings](https://bitbucket.org/bkroeze/django-livesettings) does that, but I wouldn't recommend it. I had problems with it a couple of years ago I don't remember what exactly.